# Identify data in a column that are Cost Code using Power Query

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have the a dataset that is a mix of various text and numbers, and want to identify specific ones as code. Here are some scenarios I have encountered -

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 10.01.01 | Code |
| 40.001 | Code |
| 3000 | Code |
| 2000.0001 - ABC | Code |
| 500.ABC | Not Code |
| ABC DEF | Not Code |
| 01_ABC | Not Code |

Would appreciate any assistance here.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the data really abc or is that a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the expression you are looking for:

```
Column C =
IF (
    AND (
        FIND ( "ABC", 'Cost Code'[Column A], 1, 0 ) > 0,
        FIND ( "-", 'Cost Code'[Column A], 1, 1 ) = 1
    ),
    "Not Code",
    "Code"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Peter, the values I provided are just a sample scenarios, and need to account for all numbers and strings.

Comment: I think the logic would be if it does not contain an alphabet, it's code. But the example 2000.0001 - ABC is tricky, where the first part is a code. Chances are this would be one of the other codes + string to make it unique, so  maybe be done by referencing other identified code values, maybe in two steps.

Comment: Probably it would've been your task to thoroughly specify what makes a code in your context, but you didn't do that. I can only answer on what was asked and I can't anticipate what code pattern you might encounter next. I was just trying to help and now I'm surprised how your "appreciation" looks like ...

Comment: I do appreciate your responding to my query. Sorry if my wording did not clarify enough about the sample dataset being just that. Hopefully, my previous comment makes more sense.